How am I supposed to earn reputation points if I don't know enough to answer anything? Right now, I can't even upvote!
Seems like a glitch in the matrix to me.

See How do I quickly gain reputation? on the site meta

I'm just trying to "upvote," I'm not sure why I can't upvote the answer that helped me the most.

One assumes you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

When you are able to vote up/down, you are welcome to go back and upvote posts that helped you.

since you don't know enough right now, reputation can be gained just as easily by asking good questions. Start by reading [ask]
